# __add__ an uknown number of objects

Tags: python

Let me start by saying that I don't normally code in Python, and my skills are rusty, at best.

I have the following class:

```
class aClass:
    aNumber= 0

    def __init__(self, aNumber):
        self.aNumber= aNumber

    def __add__(self, *args):
        print(args)
    def __radd__(self, *args):
        print(args)
```

And I'm doing the following operation.

```
test = aClass(1)
test2 = aClass(1)
test3 = aClass(1)

test3 + test2 + test
```

*Which, ofc, when run gives me the following error:* It's not an error, I was wrong.

```
(<__main__.aClass object at 0x0000000002A6D6A0>,)
(None,)
```

I understand why I'm getting the error, I don't understand however how I can fix it.

Any pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Even a link to some documentation. I google it myself but I don't know exactly what to look for.

---

The expected output would be the number 3.

---

If I were to have the following:

```
class aClass:
    aNumber= 0

    def __init__(self, aNumber):
        self.aNumber= aNumber

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.aNumber + other.aNumber

test = aClass(1)
test2 = aClass(1)

print(test + test2)
```

The result would be 2.

I realize I'm not explaining myself properly, it's mostly because I don't know how...as sad as that sounds.

Comment: its not an Error, its the representation of an object of your class `aClass`

Comment: Why do your `__add__` and `__radd__` just print `args`? And what's the error? Your code makes no sense, so it's hard to tell how the weird output differs from the weird output you wanted unless you tell us what you wanted.

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Have you tried your `__add__` with `aNumber`?

Comment: Your `__add__` function is not valid. It shouldn't take `*args`, but only a single input parameter. See here: https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to this:

```
class aClass:
    aNumber= 0
    def __init__(self, aNumber):
        self.aNumber = aNumber

    def __add__(self, other):
        return aClass(self.aNumber + other.aNumber)

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return aClass(self.aNumber + other.aNumber)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.aNumber)
```

Note that `__add__` function returns a new instance instead of number, as you're again calling it on the result. Then you'll have the expected result.

Comment: Those look like `__iadd__` implementations. Shouldn't `__add__` and `__radd__` be non-mutative?

Comment: @user2357112 Those can be changed to return new instance.